# what sleep() does Rails use?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am testing a piece of Rails code that reads:

```
sleep(10.0)
```

In my RSpec tests, calling:

```
Kernel.should_receive(:sleep).exactly(1).time
```

failed and the test slept for ten seconds.  This led me to conclude that `sleep()` in a Rails program isn't calling `Kernel.sleep()`.  I verified this by changing my Rails code to:

```
Kernel.sleep(10.0)
```

... after which my RSpec tests passed (and the test didn't sleep).

This leads to a specific and a general question:

- What implementation of sleep() does Rails use (I'm running Ruby 1.9.3 / Rails 3.2.1)?
- From the interpreter, what's the easiest way to find the source code for any function?

Comment: The only other `sleep` method I can find in the ruby api is the `Mutex#sleep`, so that might be it: http://apidock.com/ruby/Mutex/sleep

Comment: If you want to ask two questions, you should ask two questions. I chose to ignore the second question in my answer, since it has already been asked and answered several times on StackOverflow.

Comment: Jorg: Yah, I was aware of the dangers of asking two questions at once!  Thanks...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implicit receiver, when you don't specify an explicit one, is `self`, not `Kernel`. (Why would you think that?)

So,

```
sleep(10.0)
```

is roughly the same as

```
self.sleep(10.0)
```

and *not* at all the same as

```
Kernel.sleep(10.0)
```

So, it is calling [`Kernel#sleep`](http://RubyDoc.Info/stdlib/core/Kernel:sleep/) on `self` and not on `Kernel`. Which means you need to set an expectation on whatever object `self` is in that particular method.

Comment: Doh.  Of course.  That makes testing harder, since the sleep() may be several layers down and the `self` in question not readily accessible.  My solution -- not optimal -- was to change the source code to explicitly call Kernel.sleep().

Comment: You could monkey patch `Kernel#sleep` to raise an exception if it is called more than once or with an argument different from 10.0 and then assert that no exception is raised. Or, instead of monkey patching `Kernel`, you could monkey patch the class of whatever `self` is.

Comment: But really, it looks like you are testing the wrong thing or at the wrong level. Why would you be unable to grab a reference to the object in order to set an expectation on it? What is the *actual* behavior you want to achieve, and do you *really* care whether that particular behavior is achieved by a single call to `sleep(10.0)` or two calls to `sleep(5.0)`?